# Prevent execute previous modal after click next modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2, modal-dialog

I have one modal in one form and two different button to call this modal.
This are my two buttons

```
<?= Html::button('Search Ticket', [
    'value' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/ticket-timbangan/list'),
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary showModal',
    'id' => 'BtnModalTicketList',
    'title' => 'List Ticket Timbangan',

]) ?>

<?= Html::button('Search Contract', [                        
    'value' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('/contract/list'),
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary showModal',
    'id' => 'BtnModalContractList',
    'title' => 'List Contract',
]) ?>
```

Modal will show list of tickets or contracts to be selected by user to fill new data (as reference) and the return is `Json::encode`.
my modal code:

```
Modal::begin([
    'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'closeButton' => [
        'id'=>'close-button',
        'class'=>'close',
        'data-dismiss' =>'modal',
    ],
    'class' => 'style=width:auto',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'backdrop' => false, 'keyboard' => true
    ]
]);
echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
```

and in the script for showing up the modal

```
$(document).on('click', '.showModal', function(){    
    if ($('#modal').hasClass('in')) {
        $('#modal').find('#modalContent')
                .load($(this).attr('value'));
        document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
    } else {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
                .find('#modalContent')
                .load($(this).attr('value'));
        document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
    }
});
```

script in the action list would be like this after user click selected row

```
$(document).on('click', '.select-row', function(){        
    // get id from custom button    
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.get('../ticket-timbangan/get-ticket', {id : id}, function(data){
            var data = $.parseJSON(data);                    
            $('#pengirimanproduksi-ticket_id').val(data.id);
            $('#pengirimanproduksi-vehicle_id').val(data.vehicle_id).trigger('change');
            $('#pengirimanproduksi-item_id').val(data.item_id).trigger('change');            
            $('#pengirimanproduksi-bruto_tbg').val(data.bruto);
            $('#pengirimanproduksi-tara_tbg').val(data.tara);
            $('#pengirimanproduksi-remark').val(data.remark);            
    });
    $('#modal').modal('hide');        
});
```

the issue is when user click first button let's say ticket button to show up modal contains list of tickets to be selected. after click select, it was OK. but if user click second button let's say contract button to show up modal contains list of contracts to be selected and select one data. after event close the modal, it would execute script from first modal (which is ticket).
how to prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean if user clicks `Search Contract`  without clicking `Search Ticket` it loads the list from the tickets section rather than the `contract`.

Comment: No. it load perfectly but first if click ticket button and then click contract button, it would execute ajax called first time from ticket button (not show the modal, just execute script `$.get('../ticket-timbangan/get-ticket', {id : id}, function(data){...}`). if i click twice ticket button, and then contract button, it would execute twice also.

Comment: This css class `select-row` i assume you have it on both gridviews. my suggestion. use 2 different classes for the 2 grids. and add an on-click event for the second grid. And close the modal-rather than hide

Comment: i try first, and tell you later. thanks.

Comment: Kalu, you're genius. just only need define two different classes. `select-row` to make it different.